# Remove nodes satisfying condition and then the parent if empty

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to remove all element nodes satisying a condition and then the parent node if it remains without children.

I succeeded removing all children satisfying my condition, but have no idea how to remove the parent if it remains empty.

```xml
<root>
  <parent>
     <childA>
        <grandchildX>03</grandchildX>
        <grandchildY>02</grandchildY>
     </childA>
  </parent>
</root>
```

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="childA[grandchildX[text()='03']][grandchildY[text()='02']]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT stylesheet must output the `<parent>` when it has other children than `<childA>` (e.g `<childB>`) (this already works).

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? XSLT 3 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 and later and AltovaXML 2017 and later) has an `xsl:where-populated` that allows expressing such conditions.

Comment: It is Xalan, the standard processor provided by Java. This means there is no support fo XSLT 3.

Comment: But with Xalan the use of `version="2.0"` in your sample doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: My stylesheet is compatible with `version="1.0"`, isn't it? I suppose Xalan ignores the `version` attribute, because it does not throw any exceptions with `version="2.0"`.

Comment: Yes, I just assumed because of the `version="2.0"` that you already used some version of Saxon 9 with XSLT 2 and could perhaps easily move to actual versions of XSLT 3 with that particular `xsl:where-populated` construct. For XSLT 1 it is not so easy and elegant, will see if I can come up with a pattern or probably other posters will have an answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XSLT 3 (and assuming `xsl:strip-space`) you can use `xsl:where-populated` in the template for the `parent`:

```
  <xsl:template match="parent">
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>
```

Complete stylesheet would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="childA[grandchildX[text()='03']][grandchildY[text()='02']]"/>

  <xsl:template match="parent">
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <xsl:next-match/>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online example using Saxon 9.8 HE at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGdh.

For XSLT 1 I think you can try an empty template

```
<xsl:template match="parent[childA[grandchildX[. = '03']][grandchildY[. ='02']] and not(*[not(self::childA[grandchildX[. = '03']][grandchildY[. ='02']])])]"/>
```

i.e. the complete code would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="childA[grandchildX[. = '03']][grandchildY[. ='02']]"/>

    <xsl:template match="parent[childA[grandchildX[. = '03']][grandchildY[. ='02']] and not(*[not(self::childA[grandchildX[. = '03']][grandchildY[. ='02']])])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGdh/1

Comment: Migrating to Saxon would have worked but given that we use XLST only for cosmetic logic, we'll stick to Xalan. You solution with XLST 1.0 works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I think you can simplify your current template matching `childA` to this...

```
<xsl:template match="childA[grandchildX = '03' and grandchildY ='02']"/>
```

Then, to remove the parent elements, you need a template to match `parent` elements that all children matching that condition:

```
<xsl:template match="parent[count(*) = count(childA[grandchildX = '03' and grandchildY ='02'])]" />
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQgj/1

The disadvantage of this is specifying the same condition in two places. An alternate approach would be to do something like this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <xsl:variable name="children" select="childA[grandchildX = '03' and grandchildY ='02']" />
        <xsl:variable name="otherChildren" select="*[count(.|$children) = count($children) + 1]" />
        <xsl:if test="$otherChildren">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$otherChildren" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your first idea is great, even though some logic is duplicated, but has the advantage of being compact.

Comment: I will approve Martin's answer because he was a bit quicker and his idea does not count nodes (and thus a bit more performant).

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned in my answer that using count might not be efficient if you have large numbers of child nodes. Martin's answers are always the best though, even if he did have to suffer XSLT 1.0 this time... ;)